# Не выводит текст из базы в TEXTAREA

Tags: textarea, база-данных

```
    <?php
    $mysqlQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE id = $_GET[id]", $dbc) or die("ERROR");
    while ($mysqlQueryRow = mysql_fetch_array($mysqlQuery)) {
    ?>

   <textarea rows="18" cols="60"><?= $mysqlQueryRow['text1'] ?></textarea>
```

У меня в таблице все значения выводятся как надо, кроме ячейки TEXTAREA, что не так?
https://pp.vk.me/c623819/v623819614/5012/GxtMxIyq1K0.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте содержимое массива, есть ли в нем искомое значение? `print_r($mysqlQueryRow);`

Comment: Да, есть, выводит заданные через форму ранее значения, но не отображает их в поле:
https://pp.vk.me/c625217/v625217614/58fa/HQiD3iJe0NY.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, переменная `$mysqlQueryRow['text1']` пуста.

Comment: В базу значение записывается нормально, я проверял

Answer (score 0):

Хотелось бы увидеть чуть больше, чем `<?= $mysqlQueryRow['text1'] ?>`.
Может, в запросе не указано, что надо доставать данные из ячейки `"text1"`, например.

Comment: Добавил в шапку запрос в базу.